# I've created a hook that will read my browser's device permissions, but it re-renders constantly. How do I prevent that and render once? (w/ updates)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, permissions

So I've created a hook that will read my browser's devices and their permissions:

```
/**
 * @param {PermissionName} name The permission name will be checked. Will be one of
 * "geolocation" | "notifications" | "persistent-storage" | "push" | "screen-wake-lock" | "xr-spatial-tracking";
 * @returns {PermissionStatus} permission
 */
export const useCurrentDevicePermissions = (name: PermissionName): PermissionStatus | undefined => {
  const [permission, setPermission] = useState<PermissionStatus>();

  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.permissions.query({ name }).then(setPermission);
  }, [permission]);

  return permission;
};
```

and it's being used like this:

```
const cameraPermissionState = useCurrentDevicePermissions('camera' as PermissionName);
```

Which works, and will update when the permissions update. However, when I log this out, I get a bunch of logs (presumably because it's constantly checking for new permissions):

[image: permissions screenshot w/ console.log]

I've tried `useMemo` but I'm not entirely sure if that's the solution. How do I render this hook once soo it'll look something like

```
{
  name: 'video_capture', state: 'prompt', onchange: null
} // log once
```

and once `granted` or `denied`

```
{
  name: 'video_capture', state: 'granted', onchange: null
} // log once
```

Comment: You've created a loop using `[permission]);` as a dependency. Replace with `[name]);`.

Comment: @OriDrori Thanks for this. However, when I changed it to `name` it didn't update or log anything new after accepting the permission 

Comment: See answer with a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a loop using `permission` as a dependency if the `useEffect` block. When the `permission` changes, `useEffect` triggers, and sets the `permission` state with a new object causing `useEffect` to trigger...

Since the `useEffect` uses the `name` parameter in the callback, and you want it to trigger when the name changes use it as the dependency.

If you want to track permission status changes, register to the `change` event of the [`PermissionStatus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PermissionStatus) object.

Example:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const useCurrentDevicePermissions = (name) => {
  const [permission, setPermission] = useState(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.permissions.query({ name }).then(setPermission);
  }, [name]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!permission) return;
    
    const changeHandler = e => setPermission(e.target);
    
    permission.addEventListener('change', changeHandler);
  
    return () => {
      permission.removeEventListener('change', changeHandler);
    };
  }, [permission]);
    
  return permission;
};

const Demo = () => {
  const permission = useCurrentDevicePermissions('notifications');
  
  if(!permission) return null;
  
  return (
    <div>{permission.name} is {permission.state}</div>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Demo />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I see -- what initially worked for me with `permission` in the dep arr is that I didn't need to reload the page to get the updated status. That said when I tried this way it seems like I'd have to do that to get my updated permission. Is there a way around that?

Comment: This actually worked! With some slight change to the first `useEffect` and removing `name` in that argument. I didn't know about the usage of `addEventListener` either. This is amazing -- thank you SO much!!!

Comment: You're welcome :)
See last update.